# Is there a better way to cross-purpose technical academic questions?

Tags: discussion

Lately I've seen a few questions asked on Academia that are academic in scope but might benefit from a little help from other parts of SE because of their technical nature.  Some examples:

[Examples of research resources for which Wikipedia is known as being amongst top referrers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41831/examples-of-research-resources-for-which-wikipedia-is-known-as-being-amongst-top)

[What is the best way to design a paper questionnaire to support scanning and converting to raw data?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/43353/what-is-the-best-way-to-design-a-paper-questionnaire-to-support-scanning-and-con/44558#44558)

Pushing these questions over to, say, StackOverflow is (rightly) going to have the reviewers there closing them immediately due to being off topic, etc., but do we maybe lose the benefit of the entire community of StackExchange by not allowing for more cross-pollination?  Because a lot of these questions go unanswered as a result of not being a great fit for either community, is there a better place to ask them?  Chat, maybe?  Something else?  Is there a role for hybrid SE communities?

Just a thought...

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no systematic way to cross-promote questions. It would be nice if there were a tab on the home page that might show "related" questions from across the network, but that's a feature request above our pay grade.

Comment: ... which a lot of people want.

Answer (score 2):

You can always post a link to the question in the chatroom of a site that might be interested.

If you post the question URL on a line to itself in chat, with no other text on that line, then the chat system will create a onebox with a preview of the question, and a link to it.

Don't do it *often* in the same chatroom, because that will feel spammy. And do check the local customs of each chatroom beforehand.

And do add a sentence of explanation before or after the line with the URL on it, mentioning why you're bringing it to that particular chatroom's attention.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it might be something like that.  I'm gonna try that...